# MVC 2 Twitter Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, twitter

This is my first time here so I apologize in advance if this question is not relevant here. I have just started to learn C# and MVC 2. Most of my learning so far has been from examples and I wanted to learn from an example which I can learn a lot from.

So my example is I want to create a C# web-app for twitter. Meaning the web application that has a text box and a submit button using MVC 2 and entity framework and When any content is submitted via the text box, the content is posted to a Twitter account. The content and twitter id are logged to a database and the form is shown again with the most recent content on the page.

Much obliged to anyone who can help/guide me on this and truly appreciate the help.

Derek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download and follow the tutorial:

http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=mvcmusicstore

Pretty much everything you want to learn about MVC is shown there. Granted it's MVC3 but you might as well start learning with the newest version.

Answer (score 1):

[LinqToTwitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/) is one library that I used. I used it for a different purpose but it has the APIs that will help you build what you want. There are plenty more libraries which will help you building a twitter client if you wish to explore more.

Other post by Sergio has already pointed you to a right place regarding MVC.